# Is there an issue in SSIS with logging only child tasks but not its parent container?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a bug on the Logging mode property on SSIS?

I understand that tasks should inherit the logging mode from the parent container but by setting a container with logging mode = *`Disabled`* and the task inside the container as logging mode *`Enabled`*, I would expect that the container wont log the actions and that the task will. I would do this to avoid duplication on the log table due to nested components.

But this is not happening, if I set the logging mode on a container to Disabled, it seems to disable it at all the task that belong to the container, even though their logging mode is set to enabled.

I found this text which pretty much confirms the behavior I am expecting, but that's not whats happening.

Any thought on the matter?

> Logging can be configured at different levels in the SSIS object
>   hierarchy—at the package level, the container level, and the task
>   level. When determining which event properties should be captured by
>   which SSIS object, you should keep in mind that SSIS object hierarchy
>   supports inheritance: tasks can either use proprietary logging
>   settings or they can inherit them from the parent object (container or
>   package). If a particular branch of the SSIS object hierarchy should
>   be configured to log the same events and the same set of properties,
>   you can place the whole branch in a container to avoid having to
>   configure every single SSIS object; after logging has been configured
>   at the container, the other objects it contains will use the same
>   settings, as long as inheritance is enabled. When the LoggingMode
>   property for a particular SSIS object is set to UseParentSetting
>   (which it is by default), the logging settings will be inherited from
>   the parent in the SSIS hierarchy (the container if the object is
>   placed in a container, or the package itself if the object exists in
>   the scope of the package). Of course, the parent must be configured
>   for logging, either directly or via inheritance.
>
> On the other hand, to configure logging for a particular task
>   differently from its parent, you must set the LoggingMode property to
>   Enabled and configure the task separately. To prevent a task from
>   logging its events, set the LoggingMode property to Disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to individually configure the child tasks within the parent container, which has *`LoggingMode`* property set to **`Disabled`**.

#### Sample package created in SSIS 2012 to illustrate logging:

Here is a sample SSIS package that illustrates how the logging should be configured for the scenario you have described in the question. I have configured a package as described below.

- Create an SSIS package, say name it as `SO_14982991.dtsx`
- Create an *OLEDB Connection Manager* to the database where you would like to configure logging, if you prefer to log to an SQL Server database. This example uses the connection manager named **`OLEDB_PracticeDB`**.
- Drag and drop a `Sequence Container` onto the Data Flow tab. Rename it as simply *`Container`*.
- Drag and drop a `Data Flow Task` inside the *Sequence Container*. Rename it as *`Task within container`*.
- Drag and drop another `Data Flow Task` and place it below the *Sequence Container*. Rename it as *`Independent task`*.
- Change the *LoggingMode* property of the *Sequence Container* from *UseParentSetting* to **`Disabled`**.
- Change the *LoggingMode*  property of the *Data Flow Task* named as *`Task within container`* from *UseParentSetting* to **`Enabled`**.

[image: Sample package]

- To enable logging, click SSIS menu and then click Logging...

Perform the following steps on `Configure SSIS Log: SO_14982991`

- Select **`SSIS log provider for SQL Server`** from the *Provider type*
- Check the box under Name column
- Select the connection manager *`OLEDB_PracticeDB`*

[image: Logging 1]

Perform the following actions to enable child actions and to disable parent actions.

- Uncheck the box against the parent container named `Container`.
- Check the box against the child task named `Task within container`.
- You then need to select the child task and then check box under Name column on **`Providers and Logs`** tab.
- Choose appropriate events to log on the **`Details`** tab.
- Click OK.

[image: Logging 2]

Before executing the package, I execute the below query against the logging database to find no records.

```
select id, event, source, starttime, endtime from dbo.sysssislog
```

[image: Before execution]

Executed the package and then ran the query again to find the following records.

- You can notice that *`OnInformation`* event of the child task **`Task within container`** has been captured but not the events of its parent container.

[image: After execution]

Hope that helps to answer your question about logging only child tasks within a parent container that logging disabled.

Comment: ahhh thanks very much! The whole issue was that I was not doing this: "You then need to select the child task and then check box under Name column on Providers and Logs tab." so even though I was selecting the container to og, I was not selecting the log provider